# How to drink from a fountain?

Tags: dungeon-crawl-stone-soup

For the life of me, I just can't work this out. I can't seem to locate it in the help (certainly not in the keyboard shortcuts overview accessed using ??) and quaffing doesn't work.

I'm playing using version 0.15 and definitely remember being able to do this in earlier versions (0.13 IIRC).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ah... so you can no longer do this!

From the [official wiki](http://crawl.chaosforge.org/Fountain):

> [Fountains] are almost entirely cosmetic, but do count as water tiles for some purposes.

With the footnote:

> Prior to 0.14, you could quaff from fountains for various effects.